# How to view pixel values of an image in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

In versions of MATLAB like 2014A, it was easy to see the value of a grayscale/RGB image. We would just hover over the image with the mouse pointer to get the value.

This does not seem to be case for Matlab 2017A. How can this feature be enabled?

Comment: I don't recall that being a default feature when viewing images in MATLAB. There are options in the Image Processing Toolbox for doing this (see [Ray's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45986158/52738)), and [interactive data cursors](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datacursormode.html) that allow you to click to see pixel info. Are you sure you weren't using some custom image viewer/GUI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the image processing toolbox, use [`impixelinfo`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/impixelinfo.html).  Make sure the figure is open first, then type this command into the MATLAB command prompt.  You can then hover your mouse over the image and you can see the intensities on the bottom left corner of the figure.

Here's an example of it in action<sup>1</sup>:

[image]

Do note that the coordinates are reversed where `X` is the **column** coordinate while `Y` is the **row** coordinate.

<sup>1. Source: http://www.johnloomis.org/ece564/notes/basics/aoi/pixval1.jpg</sup>

Comment: When was the feature disabled in Matlab?

Comment: @Ashwin I've always had to trigger it manually whenever I opened a new figure.  I've never seen pixel intensities or RGB values display as you hover your mouse over the image enabled on the figure by default.  Were you perhaps using a custom GUI, or code that creates a new figure with the hovering already enabled?

Comment: It might have had to do something with either preferences or an earlier Matlab version. I did not have what you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Use [imtool](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imtool.html) (if you have the Image Processing Toolbox) to get detailed information about pixel values.

Comment: That works too. imshow with impixelinfo is better as you can zoom in more than the imtool option. Thanks.